# Displaying hour-format (am/pm or not) in Rails based on current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, localization

I just realized that the l (or localize) method in Rails (3.1.3 at the moment) appears to not manage the clock format base on the currently set locale. I have just assumed this was the case and not tested for this specifically... I have just verified that dates were re-formatted according to the locale.

I get a 24-hour clock for all of the following in my rails console. The only visible difference between the two locales is capitalization of the month name.

```
I18n.l Time.now, :format => :short,  :locale => :"en"
I18n.l Time.now + 12.hours, :format => :short,  :locale => :"en"
I18n.l Time.now, :format => :short,  :locale => :"sv-SE"
I18n.l Time.now + 12.hours, :format => :short,  :locale => :"sv-SE"
```

Now, why is that?
Is this not part of localizing a time?

The only manual intervention of AM/PM I find is in generating the selects for forms where I can demand 12-hour clock "manually". An odd choice since it feels to me like just the kind of thing I want to rely on the locale for.

Looking at Mac OS, I do get to choose the language and the locale for format preferences separately, but that is why we have the en-US, en-GB, sv-SE naming, right? Signifying language-COUNTRY. It would be perfectly OK for me to add a en-SE file to my app containing English translations by formatting suitable in Sweden.

I assume not all US-developers go in and edit the defaults locale file for English (en-US looks the same as en btw) to get a 12-hour clock suitable for US users. So, feel free to show me how dumb I am. I fully expect this problem to be sure to something really really basic.

In short. What I am getting wrong? And how do I "fix" my timestamps? :)

Answer (score 5):

You can get a 12-hour clock if you specify it directly with `%I.%m %p`: %p means indicator (“AM” or “PM”), %I means hour of the day for a 12-hour clock (01..12)

```
>> I18n.l Time.now, :format => "%I.%m %p",  :locale => :"en"
=> "01.12 pm"
>> I18n.l Time.now + 12.hours, :format => "%I.%m %p",  :locale => :"en"
=> "01.12 am"
```

This works in Rails 3.1

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is more **when** to display 12 or 24 hour times. My gut told me it should be part of the locale settings but it does not appear to be so from my testing. I cannot as you suggest without writing my own logic deciding wether to ask for 12 or 24 hour variants of the format. Running your example on the sv-SE locale prints just **01.12** since the defaults locale file sets am and pm strings to blank.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe it is more a cultural than a programming question? You can define the clock format in your I18n locale file as you like. The 12-hour clock is only used in english speaking areas, but I don't know which is more common, the 12-hour or the 24-hour clock.

Comment: I think that's the point of his question -- Different locales use different clocks (12 vs 24).  e.g. I expect en-US to use 12-hour and de-DE to use 24-hour.

Comment: Shouldn't this be something like "%I.%M %p"? Isn't %m for month?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can display the hour-format (am/pm or not) depending on the current locale, for example if you define it differently in different language/locale files. Remember there is a difference between date and time formats, if you use `Time.now` then the time format is used (if you use a Date value or typecast `to_date`, then the date format is used). The Swedish file `sv.yml` would look like

```
sv:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%H:%M"
```

The english locale file `en.yml` would look like

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: '%I.%m %p'
```

Then

```
> I18n.l Time.now, :format => :default, :locale => :en
=> "06.04 PM"
> I18n.l Time.now, :format => :default, :locale => :sv
=> "18:04"
```